# Android/Java, How to connect and get stream from IPCamera

Tags: java, android, ip-camera

I want to connect IPCamera from my android mobile and need to show the frames in surface view. Can you please suggest the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try MJpegView https://github.com/michogar/MjpegView. I tried and works fine for video. Now I'm searching a solution for the asf stream.

Comment: Thank you, i tried this and it is working fine. But i want to send commands for moving camera and get the motions. Please guide me how can we do this my vendor is: Wanscam.com